# Jquery appends new input row after filling current input row, N times

Tags: jquery, input, append

I have a table with 3 inputs in one row. What I need is, after filling all the inputs in this row, append a new row with 3 inputs which are same as before.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>W</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>X</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="h[]">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="w[]">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="d[]">
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button">x</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When user press `enter` you can add new row if all field has value and remove the closest `tr` when delete button is clicked. Following code snippet may help you.

```js
$(document).on('blur', 'tr input[type=text]:last', function() {
      var willAdd = true, tr = $(this).closest('tr');

      tr.find('input[type=text]').each(function() {
          if ($(this).val() == '')
              willAdd = false;
      });
 
      if (!willAdd || tr.next('tr').length) return;

      $('table > tbody').append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="h[]"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" name="w[]"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" name="d[]"></td>' +
            '<td><button class="delete" type="button">x</button></td></tr>');
});
        
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function () {
      var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
      if ($('table > tbody > tr').length > 1) {
         tr.remove();
      } else {
         tr.find('input[type=text]').val('');
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>W</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>X</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="h[]">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="w[]">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="d[]">
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="delete" type="button">x</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank You Azim, It's helping for me lot for my project. Can I use this function on blur event of last input of the currant row.

Answer (score 0):

is this something for you?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


        var counter = 2;
            $("#addRow").click(function(){
            $('table tr').last().after('<tr><td><input type="text" name="h[]"></td><td><input type="text" name="w[]"></td><td><input type="text" name="d[]"></td></tr>');
            counter++;
        });

    $("#delRow").click(function(){
        if($('table tr').size()>1){
            $('table tr:last-child').remove();
        }else{
            alert('You can not remove the last row from the table.');
        }
     });


})
```

And the table:

```
<button type="button" id="addRow">Add Row</button>
<button type="button" id="delRow">x</button>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>W</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>X</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="h[]">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="w[]">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="d[]">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

See it in action here:

https://jsfiddle.net/jn8cvg7f/